# Axios not returning data in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

The following axios post below returns a 200 OK status because does not return data.

```
//site.js
ifx.ajx.sendEmail = async (url, object) => {
return await axios.post(url, object, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
};
```

[image]
[image]

Here is the code for returning the data back to site.js

```
//api.ts

import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
import HttpService, { HttpTarget } from "../Services/HttpService";
const httpService = new HttpService();

const distributionOrder: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest) : Promise<string> {
    try {
        const apiRequest = (req.body) ? req.body : {};
        let body: any = {};

        body = await httpService.post(apiRequest, HttpTarget.Renderer);

        return JSON.stringify({ data: body.data.id });
    }
        
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('exception--');
        console.log(ex);
    }
};
    
module.exports = { distributionOrder };
```

Status is already sent by the request so I need to send the body.data.id only as data. But I always get the data empty in axios response even though body.data.id always has the correct value.

Comment: can you post the request config as well? or the body you send? does it have an id in the body?

Comment: what's the response you of the API? I see you are sending `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` but receive  `text/plain` in response, then I wonder about body.data.id

Comment: @ShyamKumar thank you for your reply. Request of the body mainly contains email parameters, like recipient email address, name, etc. And in response, body.data.id contains the distribution Id of the email that we can later use to track the delivery and actions performed on the email.

Comment: @PranayNailwal this is the respond ID I get in body.data.id: c4725779-1a83-4fb5-a143-3332a620ba.

Comment: if your body.data.id is already a string, why do you stringify it?

Comment: @ShyamKumar I could send it without converting but it won't resolve the problem.